# Proof of a linear transformation property

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $\phi:X \rightarrow Y$ is a map of sets and $F$ is a field. Let $\phi^* : F(Y) \rightarrow F(X)$ be a map sending a function $f \in F(Y)$ to a function $\phi^*(f) \in F(X)$ given by $\phi^*(f)(x) = f(\phi(x))$ for every $x \in X$.

How can we prove that for a scalar $\lambda \in F$, $\lambda \cdot \phi^*(f) = \phi^*(\lambda f)$ ?

Take it as axiomatic that $\phi^*$ is a ring homomorphism if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to know anything more about $\phi^*$.

By definition, we have
$$
\phi^*(\lambda f)(x)=(\lambda f)(\phi(x))=\lambda f(\phi(x))=\lambda\phi^*(x).
$$

Note: by definition, the function $\lambda f$ is given by $(\lambda f)(y):=\lambda f(y)$. This explains the middle step.